# Shopware 6 webhook for mail_template update

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

in shopware 6 is there a app webhook for every entity update (like MailTemplate )?
or only for the ones from here https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/webhook-events-reference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today these are the only write operation based events you can hook on to. The documentation will be kept up to date but you can also use the constant [`HookableEventCollector::HOOKABLE_ENTITIES`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/b2f36aac774ecbe50932df8da6228f06c7ef2512/src/Core/Framework/Webhook/Hookable/HookableEventCollector.php#L27) to check which entity events you can hook.

Comment: thanks. too bad we don't have webhooks for more entities.